# mongo/node TypeError: callback is not a function on query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, coffeescript

I am trying to determine if a document exists in a collection.  If the document exists, I wish to add a property "unread = false" to an object.  If it does not exist, I wish to insert the document and add "unread = true" to the object.

Code in coffee script for the above is as follows:

```
functionxyz = (db, uid, events, done) ->
async.each events, (eventobj) ->
    if db.Event.find(eventobj).count() > 0
        eventobj.unread = false
    else
        db.Event.insert eventobj
        eventobj.unread = true
done null, events
```

The error I am receiving is

```
/Users/owner/Desktop/coding challenge/repo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:246
        throw message;      
        ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
  at /Users/owner/Desktop/coding challenge/repo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection/commands.js:55:5
  at /Users/owner/Desktop/coding challenge/repo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1197:7
  at /Users/owner/Desktop/coding challenge/repo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1905:9
  at Server.Base._callHandler (/Users/owner/Desktop/coding challenge/repo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:453:41)
  at /Users/owner/Desktop/coding challenge/repo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:488:18
  at [object Object].MongoReply.parseBody (/Users/owner/Desktop/coding challenge/repo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:68:5)
  at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Users/owner/Desktop/coding challenge/repo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:446:20)
  at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
  at [object Object].emit (events.js:169:7)
  at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Users/owner/Deskto
```

Can someone explain to me the reason this error is occurring and what a potential solution might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MongoDB Native Driver for Node follows the Node.js convention for async functions, namely that each method receives a callback function as the last parameter.  So instead of `db.collection.find(query).count()`, your function should be rewritten as:

```
db.collection.find(query).count( function(err, count){ // do stuff here }
```

The parameter `count` captures your query's result.

You could also simplify the function to `db.collection.count(query, function(err, count){}`.

Your insert function should also follow the same convention, using a callback function with form of `function(err, res){}` as the last parameter.

I'd recommend looking at the [MongoDB Native Driver Docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#count) for more information.

*Edited to give example in CoffeeScript:*
Here's the function rewritten with CoffeeScript syntax.

```
db.Event.count(eventobj, (err, count) ->
    // do stuff
```